# Why should I NOT enclose a digit when searching for an integer?

Tags: mysql, sql

On a table where user_id is INT

Why is:

```
SELECT * FROM tableName where user_id = 63
```

recommended instead of

```
SELECT * FROM tableName where user_id = '63'
```

Comment: Because 63 is a literal integer and '63' is a literal string?

Comment: By enclosing the number your telling it to compare the number as if it were a string. You might get inaccurate results doing this.

Comment: @Steven Farley: what is "inaccurate"?

Comment: @zerkms The results that would be returned by comparing an integer to a string would not be the results intended.

Comment: @Steven Farley: any example of that? I cannot imagine how it is possible in mysql in this case. PS: mysql doesn't compare them directly, it casts first.

Comment: @zerkms To clarify I was just saying you shouldn't compare `(int) 1 = (string) '1'`. I never specified it would or wouldn't work in `MySQL`.

Comment: @Steven Farley: but you said it may cause **inaccurate results**. And in case of mysql it's not correct. " I never specified it would or wouldn't work in MySQL" --- the question is about mysql specifically. Here we discuss a particular issue. It's a programming, not philosophy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases at least in former mysql versions sometimes it happened that mysql casted left part of expression (the column) to the string, not the right to an integer.

This lead to unexpected fullscan, instead of using indexes.

I don't even mention that it just makes no sense.

Comment: I've accepted this answer but don't you think that the reason I might be asking is that I do not know? I am trying to learn and your "I don't even mention that it just makes no sense." answer really doesn't help, apologies that we don't all know what you do, isn't that what SO is all about?

Comment: @Darren Sweeney: hm, I thought that it's obvious that if you want a number - you write a number, if you need a string - you write a string (enclosed in quotes).